# Transfering small tidbits of information from Mac to iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, data-synchronization

You found that the book you were going to order online is in stock at your neighborhood bookstore (it's a near fantasy for your neighborhood bookstore to stock a book you actually want, but it's just an example! It applies for any kind of shopping list).

You copy the ISBN from your desktop browser, but rather than copy it on paper, you enter it in tool X. Tool X will make that number available on your iPhone so that it's handy when you ask for help at the bookstore.

Does Apple produce such a tool X? You could use Google Keep, or you could email yourself and pick up the mail from your phone, but I'm wondering if Apple has a native application for this use-case in its eco-system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an iCloud account, Notes does exactly this. I use it for this all the time. Just make sure you create the notes in your iCloud account. If you use a local account, it won't show up on other devices.

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple options when you're using the same iCloud account on your Mac as on your phone:

- Add it to a Notes note
- Send it to yourself as a Message
- Add it as a reminder in Reminders
- Add it as an appointment in Calendar
- Use Universal Clipboard to paste the content on your iPhone that you have copied on your Mac

Comment: ..and presumably each option depends on being logged into iCloud with the same AppleID; is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote "using the same iCloud account". Is that a problem for you?

Comment: Sheesh..! and that was *before* I got four hours of sleep.

Comment: deleting the previous comments..

Comment: At first I thought that one good solution that nails it is better than multiple solutions, none of which may strive to be good enough. But I now see the wisdom of having access to multiple modes of transfer. A shared desktop is also helpful. Since your list is on its way to be exhaustive, should sharing the desktop from a Mac to an iPhone (wherever that shows up on iOS) not also be on your list?

Comment: You cannot natively share the desktop of a Mac to an iPhone (assuming you mean sharing the desktop display similar to AirPlay Mirroring or using Remote Desktop / TeamViewer style programs). You can use third party apps such as TeamViewer, but the information is not copied/synced to your iPhone, instead it just mirrors what is on the Mac - and as soon as the connection is removed, the information is gone too.

Comment: Scenario: You are in hurry leaving your Mac. You prepare a file that you will email on the road from your phone. When the tool you use to generate the file asks you, you select the desktop. You look a little later, and the file is available on your iOS device. Can this be done?

Comment: You could just store your desktop in iCloud Drive, yes?